# CAML error when querying SharePoint List for more than one input

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I have a `CAML` query which retrieves data from a `SharePoint` list. It passes for 1 input, but fails when there are 2 or more.

**Error:**

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: One or more field types are not
>   installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these
>   fields. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: One or more
>   field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page
>   to delete these fields.
>
> ---

After researching, probable cause may be due to mismatch SharePoint column `InternalName` . However, query managed to execute for 1 input, but not 2 or more.

Base on the query examples below, am I having a wrong format for the `FAIL` cases?

---

**1. PASS:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

---

**2. FAIL:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <And>
                <Or>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Or>
                    <Neq>
                        <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
                    </Neq>
            </And>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

**3. FAIL:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <And>
                <Or>
                    <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
                    <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
                </Or>
                <Neq>
                    <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
                </Neq>
            </And>
        </Eq>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the CAML Query issue, I modify the code as below for your reference.

```
string siteUrl = "http://sp2013";
string listTitle = "DL";
string viewName="Test";

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
        SPView view=list.Views[viewName];
        string orQuery = "<Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Header1Ref\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">H1</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Header1Ref\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">H2</Value></Eq></Or>";
        string subQuery = String.Format("<Neq><FieldRef Name =\"ContentType\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">{0}</Value></Neq>", "Document");
        string queryText = String.Format("<Where><And>{0}{1}</And></Where>", orQuery, subQuery);
        var query = new SPQuery(view)
        {
            Query = queryText,
            ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"",
            ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='RecordTitle'/>",
        };

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["RecordTitle"]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The CAML Query as below.

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: Thank you @LZ_MSFT, can I check if <Or> has to be one level above <Eq>?

Comment: Check the full caml query in my reply above.